# Pythons 'DataFrame' object is not callable - FOR ERROR

Tags: python, for-loop

Good Morning, My df(df_part3) is above:

```
Postal Code Borough Neighbourhood   Latitude    Longitude
0   M5A Downtown Toronto    Regent Park, Harbourfront   43.654260   -79.360636
1   M7A Downtown Toronto    Queen's Park, Ontario Provincial Government 43.662301   -79.389494
2   M5B Downtown Toronto    Garden District, Ryerson    43.657162   -79.378937
3   M5C Downtown Toronto    St. James Town  43.651494   -79.375418
4   M4E East Toronto    The Beaches 43.676357   -79.293031
... ... ... ... ... ...
34  M5W Downtown Toronto    Stn A PO Boxes  43.646435   -79.374846
35  M4X Downtown Toronto    St. James Town, Cabbagetown 43.667967   -79.367675
36  M5X Downtown Toronto    First Canadian Place, Underground city  43.648429   -79.382280
37  M4Y Downtown Toronto    Church and Wellesley    43.665860   -79.383160
38  M7Y East Toronto    Business reply mail Processing Centre, South C...   43.662744   -79.321558
```

And My Code is Here:

```
map_toronto = folium.Map(location=[latitude, longitude], zoom_start=11)

# add markers to map
for lat, lng, label in zip(df_part3['Latitude'], df_part3['Longitude'], df_part3['Neighbourhood']):
    label = folium.Popup(label, parse_html=True)
folium.CircleMarker(
    [lat, lng],
    radius=5,
    popup=label,
    color='blue',
    fill=True,
    fill_color='#3186cc',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    parse_html=False).add_to(map_toronto)  

map_toronto
```

But When i Run it i get:

> TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
> ----> 5 for lat, lng, label in zip(df_part3['Latitude'], df_part3['Longitude'], df_part3['Neighbourhood']):

Does anyone knows how to help-me?

Comment: df_part3['Latitude'] will be a dataframe object. try to convert to a list like list(df_part3['Latitude'])

Comment: its is perfectly iterable like that. Somewhere along the line, you probably corrupted df_part3